# meta study of beta distributed posteriors

Tags: bayesian, meta-analysis

I have run 10 studies where my variable x has a beta distribution (it's between 0 and 1). I now want to infer a global/meta distribution from the local studies.

Let's say I can estimate posterior a and b for each study i.

$x_i \sim B(a_i, b_i)$

What is the best way to aggregate this?

One idea is to sum the a's and b's and then get a global x

$x \sim B(\sum a_i, \sum b_i)$

Maybe I should use the binomial distribution in my estimation.